# Jsp call another jsp

Tags: jsp, liferay

Now, I developing simple JSP portlet(no use struts).
I have the jsp view and the second jsp view_detail.jsp.
In the jsp view I wrote this:

```
<TD> <a href="<portlet:renderURL ><portlet:param name="view" value="/view_detail.jsp"/></portlet:renderURL>"><%=rs.getInt(1)%></a>
</TD>
```

but it is doesen't work.Can you help me,please.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding you correctly, you should use the API for this.

Try these steps:

In the beginning of the view.jsp you need to include the taglib:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet" prefix="portlet" %>
<portlet:defineObjects />
```

Then where you want to insert the url, put

```
<portlet:renderURL><portlet:param name="view" value="/view_detail.jsp" /></portlet:renderURL>
```

So the final `<a href>` will look like:

```
<a href="<portlet:renderURL><portlet:param name="view" value="/view_detail.jsp" /></portlet:renderURL>" target="_blank">Other JSP</A>
```

The link cannot be done your way, because the other_jsp.jsp page is displayed inside another page, so you have to link to the portal page, which then shows your jsp inside a portlet.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand,I have to create a new portlet with the view_details.jsp?

Comment: @user2273574 No the other jsp, in your case "view_details.jsp", should be in the same portlet as the view.jsp

Comment: ok I have done this.In my portlet.xml I have this  <init-param>
   <name>view-template</name>
   <value>/html/view/view.jsp</value>
  </init-param>
  
  <init-param>
   <name>view-template1</name>
   <value>/html/view/view_detail.jsp</value>
  </init-param>

Comment: @user2273574 Your parameter names in `portlet.xml` file are different to the parameter names in the code you've posted above?

Comment: Ah, yes thanks...Ihave to put in name="view-template1"... i try it now...you are welcome

Comment: @user2273574 Yes, use more descriptive parameter names rather than "view-template1"

Comment: I always  see the first jsp

Comment: @user2273574 If redirection back to the `view.jsp` happens, it means that the URL of `view_detail.jsp` has not been found and the error page is pointing back to the home page. Have you also changed the parameter name for the `view.jsp` page from "view-template" to the parameter name you have specified in your `view.jsp` document? If this doesn't fix it, then look at your error page configuration settings

Comment: I did not change "view-template" ...what is the value that i have to switch with "view-template"?

Comment: I only change now this: <TD> <a href="<portlet:renderURL ><portlet:param name="ric" value="/view_dettaglio.jsp"/></portlet:renderURL>"><%=rs.getInt(1)%></a>
 and in portlet.xml:<init-param>
<name>ric</name>
<value>/html/view/view_dettaglio.jsp</value>
</init-param>

Comment: @user2273574 Okay well I'm not sure how much more I can help you then, please edit your question and update it with all of the information you've mentioned to me in your comments so that someone else can help you. If you edit your question, it will be pushed to the top of the active list for the `jsp` tag

Answer (score 0):

```
you should follow the below code and also check in portlet.xml
<init-param>
            <name>view-template</name>
            <value>/jsp/a.jsp</value>
        </init-param>   
 <body> 
      <portlet:renderURL var="other"> 
      <portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/jsp/b.jsp"/> 
      </portlet:renderURL> 
      <a href="<%=other%>">other</a> 
    </body>
    Example
    a.jsp

    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet"%>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://alloy.liferay.com/tld/aui" prefix="aui"%>
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
        pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <portlet:renderURL var="other">
      <portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/jsp/b.jsp"/>
      </portlet:renderURL>
      <a href="<%=other%>">other</a>
    </body>
    </html>

    b.jsp

    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
        pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    hi karthik
    </body>
    </html>
```